# How to use dependency injection with .net core JwtBearerOptions.Events?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, dependency-injection, jwt

.Net Core Api for `JwtBearer` looks like this:

```
_services
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
     {
        options.Events.OnAuthenticationFailed += MyMethod;
     });
```

It's literally just a function. Now I want to use an `ILogger` that I have in the services configuration for to be used while logging failed authentication request. The problem is that I don't have the instance of the `ILogger` at this point in time and I don't really see a good way of obtaining it or using a factory method either since I don't have `ServiceProvider` either.

I have solved it like this:

```
var loggerForAuthentication = _services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<ILogger>();
```

That will build the whole DI container to return my `ILogger`. There are some downsides with this approach like e.g. generating of it's own singletons for this exact service builder and does not look right as well.

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dependency injection container is built only once when the application starts up.

The event gets fired when authentication has failed, so then there is a request happening. There is no need to build the DI container again since there is already an instance available. 
By accessing the `HttpContext` of this request we can obtain an instance of `ILogger<T>`.

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnAuthenticationFailed = MyMethod()
        };
    });



private static Func<AuthenticationFailedContext, Task> MyMethod()
{
    return ctx =>
    {
        if (ctx.HttpContext.Request != null)
        {
            var logger = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Startup>>();
            logger.LogError(0, ctx.Exception, "Token validation failed");
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I see that HttpContext does provide a Service Location (anti)pattern to use. This is not quite optimal, but can work, though it will require resolution each time while it can in practice be acquired only once. If there is not built-in DI, it's not that easy to get around anyway... It's not a good solution in my opinion, but probably the only one left considering the framework limitations...

Comment: It would make more sense to define the method as `private static Task MyMethod(AuthenticationFailedContext ctx)` instead of as a method that returns a delegate.

Comment: I had to require <ILoggerFactory>, but this set me on the right path.